# Excel data mapping using python

Tags: python, excel

I would like to open a master excel workbook and fill in a table in the master workbook with the help of data contained in other workbooks which are lying in some other directories.

The mapping of data is based on the following logic:

1. Program should first open a master workbook(say master.xls)
2. Program then should find out the value corresponding to cell A1 in the master workbook, say, the value of cell A1 is 'AB_CD_EF'.
3. Next step is to find out the workbook names lying in all 'sub-directories' and check if the filename of any of the workbook contained in all of those directories matches with the value in cell A1 of master spreadhseet.
4. If any of the workbook name matches with cell A1, program should open that workbook and pull out the data contained in a particular cell of that workbook , say cell D5 and copy it into cell B1 of master spreadsheet.
5. The prgram then should iterate through all the values contained in column A of master spreadhseet and fill in the complete table using the data contained in other workbooks (same as steps 2 to 5 above).

Hope my question is clear. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do all the heavy lifting in python you can look at this [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).  There are methods that can just put your data into arrays or dictionaries and you can do the comparison within Python.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward using the modules explained at [www.python-excel.org](http://www.python-excel.org/)